# How to do a simple Mod_Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I'm simply looking to clean a urls like:

```
/// FROM :
http://mydomain.com/about.php
http://mydomain.com/contact.php

/// TO:
http://mydomain.com/about
http://mydomain.com/contact
```

My .htaccess file:

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on


 RewriteRule ^about about.php [NC]
```

Error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /about was not found on this server.
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems i had to disable [`multiviews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) which was enabled by default.

My .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(about|contact)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid an infinite loop, you may use this in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(about|contact)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

[NC,L] may be important and rewrite_mod should be enabled by

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: Still getting 404 Not Found Error

Comment: I tested in apache2, it worked? Have you other rules in the same file or parent dir ?

Comment: No .htaccess is exactly the same as your answer. Perhaps apache settings are off?

Comment: contact.php and about.php files do exist in the same dir as .htaccess, and readable for other or owned by www-data like apache user.

Comment: They do exist in the same dir, and are readable. `http://mydomain.com/about.php` works

Comment: It seems i had to disable multiviews